# My view is lost when returning from UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

my iPad application uses UIDocumentInteractionController to preview documents. I fire it up from one of my controllers like this:

```
this.oPreviewController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl ( NSUrl.FromFilename ( sFilename ) );
oPreviewController.Delegate = new PreviewControllerDelegate ( this );
bool bCanPreview = oPreviewController.PresentPreview ( true );
```

When I dismiss the view (click the "done" button), the preview disappears but the details view I started it from is empty or UI wise coprrupt. When I use a navigation controller which is also visible and navigate back, I end up at another empty view.

When I debug, I can see that my controllers' views are NULL. What is whiping them?

Are my views garbage collected? It happens on the device only, never in simulator.

René

Comment: Are they actually null, and not just a debugger bug?  If so plese file a bug with a test case at http://monotouch.net/Support

Comment: It is not a bug but correct behavior. The views were released by GC. I had to change some of my code from ViewDidAppear into ViewDidLoad and now it works (reconnecting the UITableView's source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug but correct behavior. As memory was low, resources got released by GC. I had to change some of my code from ViewDidAppear into ViewDidLoad and now it works (reconnecting the UITableView's source for instance).